# Recurse .htaccess into subdirectories?

Tags: linux, .htaccess

On our live site, coded by other developers, we have a globals file on the root. It's auto-prepended to each requested PHP file. Great.

We're now trying to make a development server to mirror our live, for internal purposes. I'm looking in their global config for apache, and I see this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /home/site/SITE/globals.php
```

However, while making an .htaccess file, I try to call the file using the direct URL, (based on the root of the server) and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required `'opt/lampp/htdocs/globals.php'`
>   (include_path=`'.:/opt/lampp/htdocs/site/SITE/include'`) in Unknown on line 0

It seems as though it's trying to use the include path for an auto-prepend. I can confirm that if I put just globals.php, it will work in the index and files on the root of the server. Do you guys have any leads as to what the problem could be?

Replacing our config file with the live one is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto_prepend_file` is being used when you want to include php file into every php file.
there are two kind of value it can has:

1. **File name**: in this case you put only file name and php searches according site's document root (or include path).
2. *Path & file name*: in this case you put file name and the path to file.

so, if their `auto_prepend_file` has the value  `/home/site/SITE/globals.php`, so php looks in that path! so if you want to add that file into your php files you have to edit that php directive.